# I want to rewrite the GPL-2 software with AGPL-3.0

Tags: gpl-2, agpl-3.0

I would like to recreate Judge Engine of Online Judge named HUSTOJ. However, HUSTOJ was released under the **GPL-2.0 license**.

I would like to release a new Judge Engine with **AGPL-3.0**.

I know that GPL-2.0 and AGPL-2.0 are incompatible licenses. However, I left the question because I do not know whether **GPL-2.0 and AGPL-3.0 are compatible with each other**, and whether **I can set a license in this situation**.

I would appreciate it if you know this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've examined the code of HUSTOJ and are creating a very similar work, you are legally preparing a derivative work of HUSTOJ.

Generally, no, you may not license a derivative of a GPLv2-licensed work under the GPLv3 or AGPLv3. See the [GPL FAQ's compatibility matrix](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#AllCompatibility), which indicates the incompatibility (and note the statement of GPLv3 and AGPLv3 equivalency directly above the matrix).

However, since HUSTOJ is actually under GPLv2-or-any-later-version, you may receive HUSTOJ under the GPLv3 instead. GPLv3-licensed material can be included in an AGPLv3-licensed work.